# How can I set a GridView's choice mode to multiple?

Tags: android, gridview

I have this line in my code:

```
myGridView.setChoiceMode(GridView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
```

It works perfectly fine in ICS, but crashes with 2.2 and 2.3.x with the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.widget.GridView.setChoiceMode
```

However a look at [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setChoiceMode%28int%29) tells me that the method is supported from API 1, though it's inherited from `AbsListView`. I also found this [issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=16571) that reports the problem with no apparent solution

Does anyone now a workaround to this, or have an idea how to set the choice mode to multiple  for all versions?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no solution to this problem if you intend your code to run on API 10 or earlier, the implementation simply isn't there on those older versions of Android.

If you really want a GridView to have a choice mode you will need write the code yourself. The best place to put the code is in your adapter implementation.

Comment: Hi NathanZ, I'm looking at a similar problem, how did you approach this in the adapter? Thank you!

Comment: I do not understand something. `GridView` class inhereted `setChoiceMode` method from `AbsListView` and it was added in API level 1. Where it is gone?  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setChoiceMode(int)

Comment: There is some mistake in the documentation, it has not been there since API level 1, it appeared in 4.0 and later, take a look at the tags in the git commit. Git commit is here: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/commit/f343e1ba7e796120eefa917dbf78348feea98e11

Comment: You can vote on this issue: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=82135

Comment: For clarification on the "documentation error", setChoiceMode and its ilk have all existed since API 1, but they used to be found in the ListView class. In API 11, they were all moved up to AbsListView and this is when they became inheritable by GridView. So that is why the methods all say that they were added in API 1, but are only available for GridView in API 11+.
I don't think that "documentation error" is the appropriate term here since it is technically correct, but the explanation could definitely be much more clear.